# What is Darkness saying while standing in front of Wiz's shop?

Tags: japanese-language, konosuba

In episode 6 of season 2 of Konosuba, Darkness says she didn't dislike Vanir before opening the door to the shop.  I've replayed that bit of audio over and over and I just can't pick out what the middle of the sentence is.  I think I hear the end of the phrase as (かてを), but I'm not entirely sure.

まあ, きらいない ______ (かてを).

Here's the audio. Sorry for the low volume. 
http://vocaroo.com/i/s1AgdIHRUAYk

Comment: if you could maybe record that piece and add it to your post…

Comment: Audio now added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「…嫌いな奴ではなかったよ」is the phrase spoken.

Means "I did not dislike it".